# Get all the posts the user liked for a specific period

Tags: facebook-fql, where-clause

I would like to know if it's possible to get, for example, all the posts that the user liked for the last 6 month.

Tell me if I'm wrong but this query is supposed to return all posts I liked :

```
SELECT object_id, post_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me()
```

I don't see how to filter the result.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot grab the post_id that easily from the like table. The ONLY way to get a post_id is querying it from the stream table. This is no arbitrary query.

Here is how you should be thinking about it.

First you have to grab the posts from your stream that were posted by the "owner" since that's the easiest way to arbitrarily grab a bunch of posts that you care about.

```
select post_id 
FROM stream 
WHERE filter_key="owner"
```

Then you have to use that result to check if those post_ids are in your like table AND you're the user that liked them:

```
select post_id 
FROM like WHERE 
post_id in (select post_id from stream where filter_key="owner" 
and created_time> *timestamp from a week ago*)
AND user_id=me()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I was not clear in my question but I would like to get all the liked posts for a specific period, for example from last week until now.

Comment: yeah you just gotta filter on the stream query... I fixed it. Make sense?

Comment: Ok I tested the query but I changed the filter key to "others" and I added a timestamp. But the query returns an empty array... It's curious because I liked some posts since last week.